# command button onclick

Tags: visualforce, javascript, commandbutton

I have created a command button to create new contact from account object. The issue is, new contact page opens in separate tab. I want them to open in the same window.

Comment: Visual force used: <apex:commandbutton onclick="window.open('/003/e?con4={!Account.Name}&con4_lkid={!Account.Id}&&retURL=/{!Account.Id}');" value="New Rep"/>

Comment: use window.location=.........

Comment: You just need to specify the target as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267704/javascript-open-new-page-in-same-window)

Comment: Used window.location but it just refreshes the page. New contact window did not appeared.

Comment: @Dinesh try rerender="none"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using window.open('','_self')

Comment: I Answer my own question for the benefit of others. Used {!URLFOR($Action.Contact.NewContact,null,[con4_lkid=id],true)} to fix the reported issue.